# How to get the date of a Twitter post (tweet) using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract posting dates from Twitter. I've already succeeded in extracting the name and text of the post, but the date is a hard rock for me.

As input I have a list of links like these:

- https://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/1158764847800213507;
- https://twitter.com/Pravitelstvo_RF/status/1160613745208549377
- https://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/1157016227681918981

I am using searching by class, but I think this is a problem. Sometimes it works with some links, sometimes not. I've already tried these solutions:

```
soup.find("span",class_="_timestamp js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp")
soup.find('a', {'class': 'tweet-timestamp'})
soup.select("a.tweet-timestamp")
```

But none of these works every time.

My current code is:

```
data = requests.get(url)                    
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
gdata = soup.find_all("script")    
for item in gdata:
items2 = item.find('a', {'class': 'tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip'}, href=True)                            
if items2:
items21 = items2.get('href')
items22 = items2.get('title')
print(items21)
print(items22)
```

I need to have output with the posting date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe twitter API would be best choice but regaring your code....

It's available via `title` attribute of element with class `tweet-timestamp`.  This element is not within a `script` tag which seems to be where you are searching:

```
gdata = soup.find_all("script")    
for item in gdata:
    items2 = item.find('a', {'class': 'tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip'}, href=True)
```

Instead, select by the class direct:

```
data = requests.get(link)                    
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
tweets = soup.find_all('div' , {'class': 'content'})    
for item in tweets:
    items2 = item.find('a', {'class': 'tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip'}, href=True)                            
    if items2:
        items21 = items2.get('href')
        items22 = items2.get('title')
        print(items21)
        print(items22.split('-')[1].strip())
```

I prefer css selectors and you only need one class out of the compound classes:

```
data = requests.get(link)                    
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
tweets = soup.select(".content")    
for item in tweets:
    items2 = item.select_one('.tweet-timestamp')                            
    if items2:
        items21 = items2.get('href')
        items22 = items2.get('title')
        print(items21)
        print(items22.split('-')[1].strip())
```